Not able to send the message to the websocket controller in spring boot
Hi I am trying to create a web socket for a chat application,I am using websocket in spring boot and sockjs in react js for the application.
Able to send the request to cntroller but not recieving back the msg at client side.
Please find the code below:
React Js Code
/**Stomp Client */
 var msgUniqueKey=3;
    
 useEffect(() => {
     const url = "http://localhost:8080/ping";
     const sockjs = new SockJS(url);

     stompClient = new Client({
         webSocketFactory: () => sockjs,
         connectHeaders: {},
         debug: (str) => {
             console.log(str);
         },
         onConnect: (frame) => {
             console.log(`/user/user/${username}/web` +"Connected: ", frame);
             // Subscribe to user's messages /user/msg/${userName}
             stompClient.subscribe(`/user/${username}/web`, (payload) => {
                 const data = JSON.parse(payload.body);
                   setNotificationList((prev) => [...prev, {
                       id:msgUniqueKey++,
                       type:data.msg===""?"ping":"msg",
                       msg:data.msg
                   }]);
                 console.log("Received message: ", data);
             });
         },
         onStompError: (error) => {
             console.error("STOMP Error: ", error);
         },
         onWebSocketError: (error) => {
             console.error("WebSocket Error: ", error);
         },
     });

     // Activate the STOMP client
     stompClient.activate();

     // Clean up when component unmounts
     return () => {
         stompClient.deactivate();
     };
 }, []);

 const sendMsgToServer = (data,userName) =>{
  const dataToSend = {
      userName: userName,
      Type: data === "type-ping" ? "ping" : "msg",
      msg: data === "type-ping" ? "" : data,
  };
  console.log("publish msg");
   // Send a message
   if (stompClient && stompClient.connected) {
      console.log("Publishing message");
      stompClient.publish({
          destination: "/ping/web",
          body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend)
      });
    } else {
      console.error("STOMP client is not connected.");
      //setting error notification
      setNotificationList((prev) => [...prev, {
        id:msgUniqueKey++,
        type:"error",
        msg:""
        }]);
    }
}


WEB SOCKET Creation
package com.example.rakshit.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ping");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/web","/app");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ping")
            .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
            .withSockJS().setDisconnectDelay(9999999);
    }
    
     
}


Controller Code
package com.example.rakshit.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import com.example.rakshit.dto.MsgDTO;

@Controller
@CrossOrigin(origins ="*",allowedHeaders ="*")
public class PingController {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMsgTemp; 
    
    Logger log =LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    
    @MessageMapping("/web") 
    public MsgDTO pingToWeb(@Payload MsgDTO msg) throws Exception {
        log.info("PingToWeb- "+msg.toString());
        simpMsgTemp.convertAndSendToUser("/"+msg.getUserName(),"/web", msg);  // /user/$user/des
        log.info("PingToWeb2- "+msg.getUserName()+"/web");
        return msg;
    }
    
    @MessageMapping("/app") 
    public MsgDTO pingToApp(@Payload MsgDTO msg) throws Exception {
        log.info("Ping To APP"+msg.toString());
        //throw new Exception("Controller issue");
        simpMsgTemp.convertAndSendToUser(msg.getUserName(),"/app", msg);
        return msg;
    }
} 


I tried to search google saw some videos and read some code for websocket still not able to catch the issue here, also tried Chat GPT but still no result.
I am not able to get the response back from my controller i.e.subscription not working.
